# Entity Framework Snowflake Connection Failure

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect to a Snowflake database to my .Net 6 project using Entity Framework, similar in the way I connected a basic sql database.

```
services.AddDbContext<SnowflakeDbContext>(options =>
        {
            var connectionString = config.BaseConfiguration.GetConnectionString("SnowflakeConnectionString");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
                throw new SystemConfigurationException("'SnowflakeConnectionString' is missing from configuration");

            var dbConnection = new SnowflakeDbConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString = connectionString
            };

            options.UseSqlServer(dbConnection);
        });



public class SnowflakeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SnowflakeDbContext(DbContextOptions<SnowflakeDbContext> options) :
        base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

My connection string looks like this:

```
"SnowflakeConnectionString": "ACCOUNT={account};HOST={aacount}.east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com;USER={user};PASSWORD={password};ROLE={role};WAREHOUSE={warehouse};DB={dB};SCHEMA={schema}",
```

However, I am receiving this error message anytime I try to retrieve data from Snowflake.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'account'.'

Here are the packages I have installed in my project.

[image]

Can someone help me understand why this isn't working?

Comment: It looks mostly correct when compared to https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net. Could this be the issue? `options.UseSqlServer(dbConnection);`

Comment: What would the fix be if that's the problem?